# Ajax обработка форм обратной связи

Tags: wordpress, ajax

Доброго времени суток помогите пожалуйста создать форму обратной связи на AJAX. Я много времени потратил на это но у меня не чего не получается. У меня на сайте есть шесть чекбосов с выбором ответа, поле имя и телефон мне нужно сделать что бы когда пользователь нажал на чек бокс с выбраной им проблемой, заполнил поля имя и телефон нажал на кнопку ко мне приходили данные на почту с его выбором именем и телефоном. Еще хотелось бы что бы и на телефон приходило оповещения когда клиент обратился на сайте за нашими услугами но это не главное. У меня это вызывает 404 ошибку могли бы вы помочь мне разобраться

````
        <!--======== чекбоксы или радиобоксы, от замены типа инпута вид не изменится =======-->
        <div class="checkbox-group checkbox-group--grid">
            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="problem[]" value="Засорилась скважина" >
                    <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
                    <p>Засорилась скважина</p>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="problem[]" value="Перестала поступать вода" >
                    <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
                    <p>Перестала поступать вода</p>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="problem[]" value="Щелкает реле" >
                    <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
                    <p>Щелкает реле</p>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="problem[]" value="Заканчивается вода" >
                    <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
                    <p>Заканчивается вода</p>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="problem[]" value="Не работает насос" >
                    <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
                    <p>Не работает насос</p>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="problem[]" value="Другая причина" >
                    <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
                    <p>Другая причина</p>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <div class="form-item">
                        <input type="text" name="callbackfio" value="" class="required" placeholder="Имя">
            <span class="error_callbackfio"></span> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
                <input type="tel" name="callbacktel" value="" class="tel required" placeholder="Телефон">
            <span class="error_callbacktel"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="agree-text agree-text--accent">
                <input type="hidden" name="iagree" value="" class="required">
                <label class="label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="iagree" id="iagree-problems" value="I agree that:">
                    <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
                    <p>Заполняя форму, Вы даете согласие на обработку персональных данных</p>
                </label>
                <span class="error_iagree"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-btn">
                <button class="btn-accent" type="submit">Получить консультацию</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <input type="hidden" name="af_action" value="ae5f21e893618aea8dc0bf07e973d0df" />
    </form><div id="answer3" class="alert2 alert-info d-none">
    <p>Спасибо за обращение, сообщение отправлено.<br> Наш менеджер перезвонит вам в ближайшее время.</p>
    </div>                      
                </div>

  Код обработчика php
function send_ajax_form() {
    if (!isset($_POST['action']) || $_POST['action'] !== 'send_mail_ajax') {
        wp_send_json_error('Invalid request');
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['callbackfio']) || empty($_POST['callbackfio'])) {
        wp_send_json_error('Invalid name');
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['callbacktel']) || empty($_POST['callbacktel'])) {
        wp_send_json_error('Invalid phone');
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['iagree'])) {
        wp_send_json_error('You must agree to the terms');
    }

    $to = 'sales@skvazhinaremont.ru';
    $subject = 'Новая заявка с сайта';
    $message = '';

    $message .= 'Имя: ' . sanitize_text_field($_POST['callbackfio']) . "\n";
    $message .= 'Телефон: ' . sanitize_text_field($_POST['callbacktel']) . "\n";
    $message .= 'Согласие на обработку персональных данных: Да' . "\n";

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        wp_send_json_success('Form submitted successfully');
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Unable to send email');
    }
}

function my_ajax_script_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/components/ajaxform/js/default.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('my-ajax-script', 'myScript', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'name' => wp_get_current_user()->display_name
    ));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_ajax_script_enqueue_scripts');

// Регистрируем обработчик Ajax запроса
add_action('wp_ajax_send_mail_ajax', 'send_ajax_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_mail_ajax', 'send_ajax_form');

js обработчика 
var AjaxForm = {

    initialize: function (afConfig) {
        if (!jQuery().ajaxForm) {
            document.write('<script src="' + afConfig['assetsUrl'] + '/js/lib/jquery.form.min.js"><\/script>');
        }
        if (!jQuery().jGrowl) {
            document.write('<script src="' + afConfig['assetsUrl'] + '/js/lib/jquery.jgrowl.min.js"><\/script>');
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.jGrowl.defaults.closerTemplate = '<div>[ ' + afConfig['closeMessage'] + ' ]</div>';
        });

        $(document).off('submit', afConfig['formSelector']).on('submit', afConfig['formSelector'], function (e) {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {pageId: afConfig['pageId']},
                url: afConfig['actionUrl'],
                beforeSerialize: function (form) {
                    form.find(':submit').each(function () {
                        if (!form.find('input[type="hidden"][name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').length) {
                            $(form).append(
                                $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
                                    name: $(this).attr('name'),
                                    value: $(this).attr('value')
                                })
                            );
                        }
                    })
                },
                beforeSubmit: function (fields, form) {
                    //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
                    if (typeof(afValidated) != 'undefined' && afValidated == false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    form.find('.error').html('');
                    form.find('.error').removeClass('error');
                    form.find('input,textarea,select,button').attr('disabled', true);
                    return true;
                },
                success: function (response, status, xhr, form) {
                    form.find('input,textarea,select,button').attr('disabled', false);
                    response.form = form;
                    $(document).trigger('af_complete', response);
                    if (!response.success) {
                        AjaxForm.Message.error(response.message);
                        if (response.data) {
                            var key, value, focused;
                            for (key in response.data) {
                                if (response.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                    if (!focused) {
                                        form.find('[name="' + key + '"]').focus();
                                        focused = true;
                                    }
                                    value = response.data[key];
                                    form.find('.error_' + key).html(value).addClass('error');
                                    form.find('[name="' + key + '"]').addClass('error');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        AjaxForm.Message.success(response.message);
                        form.find('.error').removeClass('error');
                        form[0].reset();
                        //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
                        if (typeof(grecaptcha) != 'undefined') {
                            //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
                            grecaptcha.reset();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        $(document).on('keypress change', '.error', function () {
            var key = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            $('.error_' + key).html('').removeClass('error');
        });

        $(document).on('reset', afConfig['formSelector'], function () {
            $(this).find('.error').html('');
            AjaxForm.Message.close();
        });
    }

};


//noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
AjaxForm.Message = {
    success: function (message, sticky) {
        if (message) {
            if (!sticky) {
                sticky = false;
            }
            $.jGrowl(message, {theme: 'af-message-success', sticky: sticky});
        }
    },
    error: function (message, sticky) {
        if (message) {
            if (!sticky) {
                sticky = false;
            }
            $.jGrowl(message, {theme: 'af-message-error', sticky: sticky});
        }
    },
    info: function (message, sticky) {
        if (message) {
            if (!sticky) {
                sticky = false;
            }
            $.jGrowl(message, {theme: 'af-message-info', sticky: sticky});
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        $.jGrowl('close');
    },
};```
````

Comment: 1. Что у Вас в `afConfig['actionUrl']`. 2. У вас не указан `action` в `data` я вижу на бекенде проверку на `send_mail_ajax`, но вообще Ваша аякс логика без экшна и так не отработает, потому в ней смысла нет. 3. Если Вы передаете `dataType: 'json'`, то на бекенде его нужно распарсить, прежде всего. 4. Зачем все это, если Вы используете WP, может проще плагином форм воспользоваться?

Comment: Когда я использую плагин стили на моем сайте меняться а я хотел бы что бы стили не изменялись

Comment: afConfig['actionUrl'] должна выводить action ссылку на файл обработчик который находиться в корневой директории темы <form method="post" class="ajax_form" id="problems-form" action="mail_ajax.php">

Comment: Эммм, Вы же в курсе что в WordPress аякс работает немножко иначе?  Если там так и указано `action="mail_ajax.php"`, то работаеть это конечно же не будет. Зачем тогда это `'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` и локалайз скрипт вообще?

Comment: Ну а что тогда делать что бы это работало на моем сайте?

Comment: Документацию почитать прежде всего: [Ajax в WordPress](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html)

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что вы имеете в виду но я пытаюсь подключить через плагин который я создал в в админ панели wordpress. код из обработчика поместил в файл плагина и добавил так ` /*
Plugin Name: Ajax запросы 
*/
add_action('wp_ajax_send_mail_ajax', 'send_ajax_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_mail_ajax', 'send_ajax_form');`

Comment: Для того чтобы хук сработал, Вам нужно отправить `POST` запрос вот сюда `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')`, при этом указав `action: 'send_mail_ajax'` в объекте `data` а не указывая прямой путь к Вашему обработчику. Почему так нельзя? Потому что это просто не будет работать, начиная с того что путь к нему скорее всего не верный, заканчивая тем, что когда запрос уйдет туда напрямую, WordPress со всеми его хуками и ф-циями не будет инициализирован. Вот это `if (!isset($_POST['action']) || $_POST['action'] !== 'send_mail_ajax')` абсолютно ни к чему, так как без `action` хук и так не сработает.

Comment: Более подробно я описал в этой ветке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1511810/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-ajax

Comment: Это ничего не меняет, там +/- та же информация и тот же код.